# Accessing flask variable in react frontend

Tags: reactjs, flask

I am working with this flask react template project here and I am running into an issue

https://github.com/bonniee/react-flask

When rendering index.html, I want to pass back some data from flask

```
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
  return render_template('index.html', somedata="YOOOO")
```

And use it in the react components

```
render() {
    this.loadDataFromServer();

    return <h1>sup? {{somedata}}</h1>;
  }
});
```

Is there a clean way to do it in this project format?

Answer (score 1):

In your template, you could include a `script` tag that sets `window.somedata` to the value you want. You could then access that directly in render, or preferably if you've got flux or redux you could dispatch an action with that data during mounting of the react components.